# remove admin bar new post/link/media sub menu

Tags: admin-bar

I wish to remove the sub menus of post/link/media under the add new menu in the admin bar. I can remove the entire menu but I actually only want to remove the sub menu's

```
$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('my-account-with-avatar');
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See the Admin Bar [remove_node](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_node) function:

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_wp_nodes', 999 );

function remove_wp_nodes() 
{
    global $wp_admin_bar;   
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-post' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-link' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-media' );
}
```

Comment: I have the code in my plugin, I have also tried calling - global $wp_admin_bar; insidne the function

Comment: @Keith, code tested and working now.