# Change order of an item under "New" on the admin bar

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-bar

The Admin Bar has a menu with shortcuts for adding new content.

By default, it shows "Post", "Media", "Page" and "User".

[image]

I'm using `register_post_type` to register a new custom post type. I can use its `menu_position` property to change the position in the dashboard menu, but how can I reorder the shortcut link so it will show higher, instead of just above "User"?

Comment: Possibly related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/76642/22510

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar situation. My custom post type showed up under the Admin Bar as **Artifact**, but my clients preferred it to be at the top of the list. Plus, the items for **Media** and **User** were not really needed.

[image: WordPress New menu before]

My approach was first to user [remove_node](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_node) to take away all the ones except my custom post-type and then put back the ones I want with [add_node](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_node)

```
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'portfolio_adminbar' );

function portfolio_adminbar() {

    global $wp_admin_bar;

    // get node for New + menu node
    $new_content_node = $wp_admin_bar->get_node('new-content');

    // change URL for node, edit for prefered link
    $new_content_node->href = admin_url( 'post-new.php?post_type=portfolio' );

    // Update New + menu node
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($new_content_node);

    // remove all items from New Content menu
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('new-post');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('new-media');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('new-page');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('new-user');

    // add back the new Post link
    $args = array(
        'id'     => 'new-post',    
        'title'  => 'Blog Post', 
        'parent' => 'new-content',
        'href'  => admin_url( 'post-new.php' ),
        'meta'  => array( 'class' => 'ab-item' )
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );

    // add back the new Page 
    $args = array(
        'id'     => 'new-page',    
        'title'  => 'Page', 
        'parent' => 'new-content',
        'href'  => admin_url( 'post-new.php?post_type=page' ),
        'meta'  => array( 'class' => 'ab-item' )
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );

}
```

Here is my menu after:

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! But is there any way to get the new top item to be the default if you just click "+ New"? In my case it still chooses Post, not the custom post type we use almost exclusively.

Comment: Ahh, that is needed. I just updated code with a few lines to do this, you may need to edit the destination link for your purposes. Borrowed this from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47927/14945

Comment: Sweet - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This section rendered via `wp_admin_bar_new_content_menu` (admin-bar.php [Line No. 690-746](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L683)) callback on `admin_bar_menu` action (class-wp-admin-bar.php [Line No. 584-588](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php#L584)).

I couldn't find any hooks to filter the menu items here. So i'm thinking of removing that action and add another action with your own sorting.

Remove this action with `remove_action` and then attach your custom callback again to add menus. Eg.

```
remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_new_content_menu', 70 );

add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpse273333_admin_bar_custom_new_content_menu', 70 );
function wpse_273333_admin_bar_custom_new_content_menu( \WP_Admin_Bar $wp_admin_bar ){
    // add your menus
    // check wp_admin_bar_new_content_menu() function for some idea
}
```