# Create post programmatically

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to create a video gallery plugin. I am using this code to create a post:

```
global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
    'post_title'    => 'chapter1',
    'post_content'  => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
    'post_author'   => $user_ID,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );
```

It's working well, but the problem is the created post shows in the admin dashboard "All Posts" panel; I don't want to show programmatically created posts there, or in the latest posts.

Is there any way I can do this? I tried to change the post type, but the generated post link gives me a page not found error.

Comment: did you change post type to a [registered type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)?

Comment: Remember to flush your permalinks after you have registered your post type, otherwise you will get a 404 error

Comment: i have little bit idea about permalink.. how can i flush permalinks.    i am using /%postname%/ type permlinks

Comment: Just visit the permalink setting page in the back end, that is all. You can also, just for extra pleasure, click on the update button on that page. This will eset and resave all your permalinks

Answer (score 2):

And to create a custom post type is not an option?

```
'post_type' => 'custom_post_type'
```

then just hide the custom post type from the UI

see [Possible to hide Custom Post Type UI/Menu from specific User Roles?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28782/possible-to-hide-custom-post-type-ui-menu-from-specific-user-roles)

Comment: how can i create custom post type. i have plugin installed in my word press website "WORDPRESS VIDEO GALLERY" it uses custom post type "videogallery" i want to make similar one like that

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I thought this would be fairly simple but seems I'm just not competent enough.

You could get around it by adding an arbitrary category (like `my_prog_cat_to_hide`) for these programmatically added posts and then filtering them out in the admin listing.

```
function wpse182434_get_category_id($cat_name){
    $term = get_term_by('name', $cat_name, 'category');
    return $term->term_id;
}

function wpse182434_filter_admin_query( $query ) {
    if(is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && !filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'post_status') && ( $screen = get_current_screen() ) instanceof \WP_Screen && 'edit-post' === $screen->id) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-'.wpse182434_get_category_id('my_prog_cat_to_hide') );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse182434_filter_admin_query' );
```

Of course this leaves you with handling stuff like not showing that category on the front end and/or in feeds and what not.

in that `wpse182434_filter_admin_query` the if conditions are so that if you select *published* or any other filter than *all posts* from the top, you still see the articles. They are just filtered out in the all posts listing.

And all this goes in your functions.php of course.

Comment: i know video gallery plugin which exactly do. what i want . its create video post , post type "videogallery" and not show in "AllPost" tab or in front end website in latest post section .  i want to make similar one like that

Comment: Well that's basically what I was suggesting before. I think you could do this via custom post type with custom post status.

Comment: i am using "Custom Post Type UI" for creating custom post type and using php code to create post now its  adding custom post type name before post name example "/customposttype/mypostcreatebyphp/" but it still give me page not found error

Comment: thanks for help and tips.  i did it as you all mentioned in comments . by using "Custom Post Type UI" and php create post code. after that i have to only flush the permalinks and its working .. thank you again .

Comment: Awesome if you got it working.